# Where does `custom.js` exist or how to create one for Jupyter 4.1.1?

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I could not find `custom.js` for Jupyter (notebook) installed under pyenv+virtualenv with Python3.5.1.

Some say that `custom.js` locates at `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js` but I do not have one (by the way, I could create `jupyter_notebook_config.py` via `jupyter notebook create`).

```
$ ls ~/.jupyter
jupyter_notebook_config.py  migrated
```

Where is `custom.js` or how to create default one?
Should I download it from the repository?

```
$ pip freeze
ipykernel==4.3.1
ipython==4.1.2
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
ipywidgets==4.1.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==4.1.1
jupyter-console==4.1.1
jupyter-core==4.0.6
```

Comment: It should live in `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js`. I don't think there's any need to create a default one - just create an empty file there and start adding to it.

Comment: @ThomasK It works. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

`custom.js` should live at `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js`. I don't think there's any need to create a default one - just create an empty file there and start adding to it.