# Why do I have no 'custom' Directory at ~/.jupyter/custom?

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to add some custom Javascript to a Jupyter notebook by using the `custom.js` they provide. On their [webpage](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/JavaScript%20Notebook%20Extensions.html#custom.js), they say you can find the `custom.js` folder at `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js`.

However, when I look for the file there, I can't see it. I don't even have a `custom` directory. Instead, I see a file called `migrated`.

Weirdly, if I run Jupyter and go `http://localhost:8888/custom/custom.js` I can see the file, but it's not present in the folder.

What's happening here? Should I just create my own custom folder?

Comment: You don't say what sort of system you are working on. The part represented by the tilde may be different. Also, the part represented by `.jupyter` means that directory is hidden. Are you accounting for that. It would seem you have that file if that `http://localhost:8888/custom/custom.js` works and you are running the typical things locally. I would not advise creating a folder at this time since that link works. I wonder if running [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39921293/8508004) in your notebook may help.

Comment: @Wayne I added the folder and file, and it seems to have worked. I've tried exploring this on three machines, two windows one mac, all with fresh Jupyter installs, and I get the same issue. After adding the folder and files I did run that code, it showed me what I pasted in there. Do you use use Jupyter? Have you come across an issue like this before?

Comment: Glad to hear it works. I was trying to play it more cautious just to avoid creating issues. I wonder if the documentation is actually worded poorly? It's stated differently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36032376/8508004) by someone who works on Jupyter. The 'should 'could be interpreted as you can make one yourself.  (The first sentence [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5069) is consistent with that expectation, too.) The language on the documentation your point out makes it like it should be there. I more often use Jupyter on JupyterHub, which is a bit different.

Comment: @Wayne, yes, it's extremely vague. Seems like a pretty huge oversight, but maybe this feature isn't used that often. Still, at least I have an answer! Hopefully my answer below is helpful for anyone else in the same situation. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Open a [terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)) and visit the path given in the documentation. Run:

```
> ls -a
```

To get a list of everything in the directory, the `-a` option includes hidden files. If the directory definitely isn't there, run the following commands:

```
> mkdir custom
> cd custom
> touch custom.js
```

In order, the first command creates the custom directory, the second command moves you into that directory, and the third creates the `custom.js` file within that directory.

To edit `custom.js` in your code editor of choice run:

```
> open custom.js
```

To edit `custom.js` directly in your terminal, run:

```
> vim custom.js
```

Hopefully, that solves the issue for everyone.